# Converting percentage number to marginTop animate in pixels value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, percentage

I need to take a percentage value, convert it to pixels and move a div upwards using JQuery animate for a progress bar I'm trying to build. The div containing the graphic that needs to move upwards has a 268 pixel height (so that is our 100%).

as an example, I put 38% as the starting percentage value that I need to convert to a pixel value and move div with the id prog_anim to that number of pixels upwards (should be around 101 pixels)

```
var result = 38 / 100 * 268;
function bgr_animate(result) {
    $('#prog_anim').animate({
    'marginTop' : result
    });
}
```

and then I have the following link on a button that performs the action:

```
a href="javascript:;" onclick="bgr_animate(result)"
```

being a total Javascript noob I have no idea where the above syntax is wrong. Can anyone correct me here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function bgr_animate(percent, height) {
    var pixels = percent / 100 * height;
    $('#prog_anim').animate({
        'marginTop' : pixels
    });
}
```

And your button;

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="bgr_animate(30, 268)">
```

Comment: actually this works fine, I just need to move it in the opposite direction. It now moves down, while I need it to move up. How to I make the "pixels" variable negative? Thanks!

Comment: `var pixels = -1 * (percent / 100 * height);`

Comment: nvm, found it anyway, Thanks for your help!

Comment: A shorter/better way is found in my answer, but basically just put the negative sign in front of the side of the equation that you want to negate.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few areas for improvement.

Instead of hardcoding 268, use `var graphicHeight = $("#prog_anim").outerHeight();`.

You'll need to reverse the direction of the margin top since you want it to move up. marginTop is one way to do that, but setting a CSS `position: absolute;` and using top instead of marginTop would be better.

So:

```
var result = -(38 / 100 * graphicHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
$('#prog_anim').animate({
      height: result
      top:-=resultInc
      }, 5000, function() {
     alert("Animated");
});
```

Where resultInc is the number of pixels by which it grows

Using this you can move upwards and increase the height downwards giving the impression that it grew upwards